# dockerizing django,nginx,gunicorn return exited code 3

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

Im new to learn this django in docker.

Im following this guide: https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/
In my lab ubuntu server 22.04, all working well until nginx part, i up and build the docker-compose.prod.yml and result the "web" services is exited by code 3.
And when i browse http://localhost:1337, it show me 502 Bad Gateway.

What is this issue? I cant found any relate error about this.

Tried to google but no luck.

Comment: can you share the logs from web service. You can get it by `docker-compose logs web`

Comment: Attaching to django-on-docker_web_1
web_1  | Waiting for postgres...
web_1  | PostgreSQL started
web_1  | [2023-01-17 06:29:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
web_1  | [2023-01-17 06:29:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
web_1  | [2023-01-17 06:29:21 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
web_1  | [2023-01-17 06:29:21 +0000] [32] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32
web_1  | [2023-01-17 06:29:22 +0000] [32] [ERROR] Exception in worker process